# can't run kivy Text Input with pycharm,but it works in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, kivy, virtualenv

I was trying to run my kivy app from pycharm by clicking the run button. it shows a blank screen.but it is works fine in terminal ( same env). and this problem is only occur if i used TextInput in my code. And if i remove the Textinput and use other things like buttons,switch etc.. it works fine with pycharm and terminal. how to solve this issue ?

[image]

this is my code

[image]

when click pycharm's run button.[image]

When run from terminal of pycharm. ( same env )

Comment: I don't know if it will solve the problem but maybe change the .kv name file from `my.kv` -> `main.kv`.
Maybe you should try to use Builder.load_file("my.kv") in the `build` method of the class `App`.

I'm more surprised that it is working on your terminal rather than surprised it didn't worked on PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you @Utopion for your reply :)  .I tried your suggestions. but it didn't solved my issue. and it shows errors when i tried your suggestions. I think the problem is not in my code. it is also working in Visual studio code and terminal .  The problem is only occur when i use pycharm's Run or Debug button.